# Access Comparing Dates

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I want to select all Dates that are older then 4 year (from right now) his is the code I have so fare. `

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ([Module]
INNER JOIN
    Teilnahme
ON
    Module.ID = Teilnahme.Modul)
INNER JOIN
    Mitarbeiter
ON
    Teilnahme.[Mitarbeiter-E-Mail] = Mitarbeiter.E_Mail
WHERE
    (((Module.Name)="ISM Forum")
    AND Teilnahme.Teilnahmedatum >= DATEADD(yy,-4,DATE()));
```

The problem is that when I get run the select I get aske what the value of year is. What shoud I change ?
I use Access 2010.

Comment: Use a quoted, four character: `DATEADD("yyyy", -4, Date()))`

Comment: thanks <3 that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Here some info about dateAdd function:

```
DateAdd ("yyyy", 3, #22/11/2003#)
Result: '22/11/2006'

DateAdd ("q", 2, #22/11/2003#)
Result: '22/05/2004'

DateAdd ("m", 5, #22/11/2003#)
Result: '22/04/2004'

DateAdd ("n", 51, #22/11/2003 10:31:58 AM#)
Result: '22/11/2003 11:22:58 AM'

DateAdd("yyyy", -1, #22/11/2003#)
Result: '22/11/2002'
```

taken from [This site](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php)